# MySQL: simplifying a complex query

Tags: php, mysql, infinite-loop, large-data

I made the following query based on many tutorials from blogs and answers on stackoverflow.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM $table f1".
"WHERE (user_id = '$userA')".
"AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM $table f2 WHERE user_id = '$userB'"
"AND f1.$field = f2.$field)")  

or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $com = $row['COUNT(user_id)'];
}
```

The parameters such as userA, userB are taken by an one-dimension array of 4000 values. But actually, i use loop inside the loop to make a table of 4000x4000 size.

Due to many data in the database, the total queries will be 17.000.000. So, i gave a try to execute the full script but i saw that at the above query took many seconds (1 or 2).

Do you have any suggestion to increase the execution speed by correcting the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a `INNER JOIN` query as below:

```
 SELECT COUNT(f1.user_id) 
 FROM $table f1 JOIN $table f2 
    ON f1.$field = f2.$field
 WHERE f1.user_id = '$userA'
    AND f2.user_id = '$userB'
```

Comment: OMG! It s really fast now! (30 per second instead of 1 per second!)

Comment: @zuperakos subselects are poorly optimized in mysql. Avoid them when possible.